# Introduction to probability/statistics question

Tags: probability

I am taking an introduction to probability course and I need help with this problem:

You and your friend were studying and you left your cell phone either in the computer lab or in the cafe (these were the only two places you visited). You think that with probability .4 it was left in the computer lab, because you always take it out of your backpack there, otherwise, it was left in the cafe. If you left the phone in the computer lab, the probability that someone stole it is .3. In the cafe, the probability that someone stole it is twice that of the computer lab.

The probability of not finding your cell phone (i.e., it was stolen) is...

What I did was:

P(stolen)= .3+2(.3)= .90
I decided to put .3 since this is the probability that someone stole the phone from the cafe and added 2 times the probability that someone stole it from the computer lab.

However, the answer is .48

If anyone could help me answer this question, I would be very grateful.Thanks.

Comment: The Answer uses the Law of Total Probability, which you should investigate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine both possibilities (leaving it in computer lab/cafe) like this (using conditional probabilities):

P(stolen) = P(leaving it in the lab)P(stolen|leaving it in the lab) + 
P(leaving it in the cafe)P(stolen|leaving it in the cafe)

Then the final result is:

$$0.4\cdot0.3+0.6\cdot0.6=0.48$$